# CATransform3D - go back to previous state

Tags: iphone, ios, catransform3d

Hi I`m working with CATransform3D.
Every time that I call the following method with the variable radian the UIImageView is rotated “radian * M_PI” from the previous angle.
I trying to go back to the original state. There is any way to do that?
I mind I want to sent a radian value i.e. 10 and that the view maintain these angle if is called more than once.

METHOD:

---

```
CATransform3D rotatedTransform = self.needleB.layer.transform;
rotatedTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotatedTransform, radian * M_PI / 180.0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
self.needleB.layer.transform = rotatedTransform;
self.needleB.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.9);
self.needleB.center = CGPointMake(160, 250);
```

---

Thanks !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To undo all transforms, assign the `transform` property of your layer to `CATransform3DIdentity`.

Comment: That is, you should replace your first line above with `CATransform3D rotatedTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;` and then the rest of the code will work just as you expected it to.